# XSL-FO include text before page breaks

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, page-break

I have a XSL file working well, printing text.

However, text is too big to fit in just one page, so it automatically goes to a second page (and third in some cases).

How can I show a text like "(continued on next page)" in the current page when a break page happens?

The show the text itself I know - my issue here is when to identify a page break, so I can make the text visible. This long text starts at a unknown page number (could start in page 2, 3, 4... depends on the size of a table before it).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `fo:retrieve-marker`. A `fo:marker` is placed in static region (like a footer or header). There are a number of examples online.

Comment: To show the text itself I know, my issue is about knowing when there are more pages, i.e., when the text continues in the next page.

Comment: You can never know about more pages because the FO processor creates the pages at runtime, but you can use `markers` along with static regions to know when to show 'continued' on the page before the break. You can have `conditional-page-master-reference` for your page sequence which can have a number of `simple-page-master` which in turn have references to static regions. Since you didn't post any code, I can't help you other then let you know that I think `markers` are the way to go.